# Gold Edition or Golden Edition?

Tags: grammar

Gold Edition or Golden Edition? Which is correct?If both are correct then what's the difference?Is there any changes in the adjective here? Plz explain in a grammatical way.Thanx all.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, when 'gold' is used as an adjective, it should mean that the item it is describing is made of gold, or at least made of an alloy that contains gold, eg On his retirement he received a gold watch. 'Golden', which is always used as an adjective, can mean exactly the same thing as 'gold', but it can also mean 'something with the same colour or sheen as gold', eg 'the golden light falling on the lake'.

In reality, 'gold' is frequently used in a figurative sense to describe something that has no gold content, e.g. 'She had green eyes, with gold flecks that lit up when she was angry'. The word 'gold' is also frequently used to indicate that something is of a higher quality, or more desirable for some reason, than another similar item, e.g. credit cards from the same provider are often distinguished as being silver or gold cards. Similarly, video games, DVDs, Blue Ray Discs, etc, are often sold as Gold Editions (or sometimes Platinum Editions), if they contain extra content that is not available in the standard editions.

Whether special editions are called 'Gold Editions', or 'Golden Editions' (or even 'Platinum Editions'), is totally of no consequence. The name is just marketing hype to attract the notice of potential buyers, and inform them that this edition contains something extra (and possibly costs a few dollars more).

Answer (score 0):

Gold Edition is essentially regular edition with some behind the scenes stuff like a normal edition e.g. *Get Gold Edition which includes the game, Season Pass and the Deluxe Pack.*
Whereas Golden Edition might refer to the yellowish or brownish-yellow metallic color of gold e.g. *The Golden Edition of the watch has been released for limited time period.*